# Python global list not being updated

Tags: python, list, global-variables

I have a global list and it seems that it doesn't update the list in the file it is declared. I have seen several question similar to my issue which I can use to fix my issue. But I was trying to understand why it does not work in my case.

**HelloWorld.py**

```
import TestFile

store_val = ["10", "20"]

def main():
    store_val.append("30")
    print store_val
    TestFile.list_val()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**TestFile.py**

```
import HelloWorld

def list_val():
    HelloWorld.store_val.append("40")
    print "Store Value : ", HelloWorld.store_val
    HelloWorld.store_val.append("60")
    print "Updated Value : ", HelloWorld.store_val
```

The problem that I see is that I am able to append a value to the list in TestFile.py but can't seem to add a value to the list in HelloWorld.py even though it is declared there. What is the best way to rectify this issue so that I can append the value from HelloWorld.py

Result of running HelloWorld

```
['10', '20', '30']
Store Value :  ['10', '20', '40']
Updated Value :  ['10', '20', '40', '60']
```

Comment: Are you saying `store_val.append("30")` did not work ?

Comment: Yes I am trying to used that append the value in HelloWorld.py and that did not update the list

Comment: Do you know how this `if __name__ == '__main__':` works?

Comment: No I don't how that works. I assuming it is just the entry point of the program

Comment: How do you run this script you have imported  one in other and vice versa ?

Comment: I know I have imported it in both.When I run helloworld.py and I was expecting "30" to be appended to that list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95684/discussion-between-vignesh-kalai-and-pete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be this way instead . In your case only the store_val list and main function gets imported from HelloWorld in TestFile.py but the main function is not run in TestFile.py

HelloWorld.py

```
import TestFile

store_val = ["10", "20"]

def main(n=1):
    store_val.append("30")
    print store_val
    if n>0:
        TestFile.list_val(n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

TestFile.py
import HelloWorld

```
def list_val(n):
    if (n>=0):
        HelloWorld.main(n-1)

    HelloWorld.store_val.append("40")
    print "Store Value : ", HelloWorld.store_val
    HelloWorld.store_val.append("60")
    print "Updated Value : ", HelloWorld.store_val

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_val()
```

Run Code:

```
python HelloWorld.py
['10', '20', '30']
['10', '20', '30']
Store Value :  ['10', '20', '30', '40']
Updated Value :  ['10', '20', '30', '40', '60']
```